# [PHP]Severity: Compile Error Message: Cannot redeclare <function> - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I have this function:

```
 function vai_a_capo($cont_sett){ ---> line 3
    if($cont_sett >= 7){
       echo "</tr><tr>"; 
       return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
 }   ---> line 10
```

I'm using CodeIgniter version: 3.1.2.

When I go to the link: ../index.php/home/pages/disponibilita it say to me:

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare vai_a_capo() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\CI___________\application\views\pages\disponibilita.php:3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\CI___________\application\views\pages\disponibilita.php on line 10`

Thanks for the answers. Bye.

EDIT:

It has been solved. In my controller (Home) I declared by mistake twice of these:

```
  $this->load->view('pages/disponibilita', $data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take care of your error messages:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare vai_a_capo() (previously declared in 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CI___________\application\views\pages\disponibilita.php:3) in > > C:\xampp\htdocs\CI___________\application\views\pages\disponibilita.php on line 10

They tell you, that the method you are trying to declare *has already been declared* in `disponibilita.php`. You have to give your method another name.

Answer (score 1):

As Paul points out.. yes you could change the function name but since your site is likely riddled with calls to this function, that would likely be a lot of work.   Instead, just check to see if the function is already defined by adding 2 lines, like this...

```
if (!function_exists('vai_a_capo')) {  // new line to go above  function
    function vai_a_capo($cont_sett){ ---> line 3
    if($cont_sett >= 7){
      echo "</tr><tr>"; 
    return TRUE;
}else{
  return FALSE;
  }
  }   
} // new line below function
```

I should point out, this edit needs to go where your code is trying to define the function a 2nd time..  In \application\views\pages\disponibilita.php on line 10